# docker compose issue while creating cassandra cluster

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose

I am doing a very simple example of creating a cassandra cluster using docker compose. After running docker-compose up, I can see the 2 cassandra containers getting created. But these are not created as part of cluster. Since when I get into one container and run 'nodetool describecluster' , it shows me only one ip. 
Here is the docker-compose.yml I am using. Please help me to find out what am I doing wrong. I have already spent lot of time in checking logs and figuring out.

```
cass0: 
 image: cassandra:3.9
 ports: 
  - "9042:9042"
  - "9160:9160"

cass1: 
 image: cassandra:3.9
 links: 
  - cass0:seed
 environment: 
  SEEDS: seed
```

Here is the nodetool cluster output:

```
Cluster Information:
        Name: Test Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                86afa796-d883-3932-aa73-6b017cef0d19: [172.17.0.3]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems, you are using a wrong keyword. Please replace it in your file.

```
 environment: 
  CASSANDRA_SEEDS: seed
```

Hope it helps.